# session attribute converting in to integer in jsp

Tags: java

i store price in session , how can i get it in integer formate

this code give me error:

```
<%=session.getAttribute("price")%>       //it print my value 400

<% Integer i=(Integer)session.getAttribute("price"); %>     //error
```

can you help me what's wrong?  and how to do?

Comment: what is the error? post it

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you're setting your attribute.

If you're setting an `Integer` object like below -

```
Integer price = new Integer(10);
session.setAttribute("price", price);
```

Then, you can get like - `Integer price = (Integer) session.getAttribute("price")` in jsp.

But if you're setting string in session like below -

```
String price = "10";
session.setAttribute("price", price);
```

Then you have to parse to integer while getting in jsp, like -

```
int price = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("price"))
```